# SSH command options cause errors when stored in a variable

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a variable that stores an SSH command, since my script uses it quite often.

```
SSH_CMD="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes"
```

However, I'm running into an issue where the SSH command works fine on its own, but doesn't work when I use the variable

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes $host exit 0
${SSH_CMD} $host exit 0
```

The first line works great. The second line fails with a `No such file or directory` message. When I remove `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` from `$SSH_CMD`, the error message is `command not found`. If I remove either of the other two options, the message doesn't change, but when `$SSH_CMD` is just `"ssh"`, it works.

What's causing this problem?

Comment: fully explained at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: So why does it work without any issues in other scripts? And is there some other way to store the command?

Comment: BashFAQ 50 lists several better ways to store the command. Actually, this particular command doesn't contain any shell metacharacters, so it shouldn't run into any of the usual problems with storing commands in variables. I can think of two things that might cause your symptom, though: are you using the command in double-quotes (e.g. `"${SSH_CMD}" $host exit 0`), and are you sure those are normal spaces in the command string (not something like non-breaking spaces, which look normal but aren't recognized by the shell)?

Comment: You should post the complete error messages - `No such file or directory` and `command not found` usually have the relevant name prepended.

Answer (score 0):

> So why does it work without any issues in other scripts?

Many times answered. Try bash alias or bash function:

```
alias my_ssh='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes'
my_ssh $host exit 0
```

Or rahter use `ssh_config` in your `~/.ssh/config`.

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
BatchMode yes
```

and then you don't need any harakiri like this and just use

```
ssh $host exit 1
```